# AngularJS problem with backing to home page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is how i config the home page:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'static/templates/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    });
```

And above this working nice.

here you got to see my nav:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="#!/add">Add New</a>
```

I have another route named: `add`

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/add', {
        templateUrl: 'static/templates/add.html',
        controller: 'addCtrl'
    });
```

Above everything working fine but the problem is: when i click on href="#!/add">Add New</a> it works good to navigate me to `add.html` page but when i click on `<a href="/">Home</a>` the page not back to home, it still stay in `add` even when i click on other route, they work, only problem with home, if i click on home, it doesn't bring me to home page

What is the problem?

Note that: When i landed to home page directly `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` it is works nice but if i switch to another page and come to home page again by click on home buttion, it is not work

Comment: What do you see in the rendered HTML ( Inspect Element ) of that anchor tag href attr?

Comment: If i  click on home page from another route, it not works, it exist on the route from where i back to the home page

Comment: Just make this line like below and try <a href="#!">Home</a>

Comment: Not works like this too

Comment: difficult to guess without complete code or refer this https://jsfiddle.net/e9pzbo0c/

Comment: I think the problem could be using $stateProvider and $routeProvider both togther. Why use both? You can have /add route using $stateProvider only.